# Error Downloading Video Files on Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

As of Friday Jan 26th 2024, our firebase cloud function has begun to fail when attempting to download video assets. We have successfully used the following setup for a year, but as of yesterday it has begun to fail without code changes on our end.

Setup:

- Firebase Admin 12.0.0
- Node 20

```
import { getStorage } from 'firebase-admin/storage';

  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  const bucket = getStorage().bucket();
  const downloadFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
 
  functions.logger.log(
    'In thumbnail creation, video downloaded locally to',
    downloadFilePath,
  );

  const downloadFile = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const stream = bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream();

      stream.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(' ~ PromptService ~ data ~ data:', data);
        return;
      });
      stream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(' ~ PromptService ~ err ~ err:', err);
        return reject;
      });
      stream.on('end', (data: any) => {
        console.log(' ~ PromptService ~ err ~ err:', data);
        return resolve;
      });
      stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(downloadFilePath));
      functions.logger.log(
        `gs://${bucket.name}/${fileName} downloaded to ${downloadFilePath}.`,
      );
    });
  };
  // Downloads the file
  console.log('downloading file');
  await downloadFile();
  console.log('finished downloading file');
```

I'm receiving console logs from the data listener with the file buffer but it fails before the error of end listeners fire.

I have also tried the download method as well with no luck. `bucket.file(filePath).download()`

I'm expecting the file transfer to finish and pipe to a write stream where I can use the file to make a screenshot.

Comment: Look up the error logs of the Cloud Function from your [developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions). Those error logs should help you to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to an issue with my cloud function runtime env (Node 20), I ended up switching to google cloud TransferManager and implementing `downloadFileInChunks` for it to work properly. `download` and `createReadStream` where having problems with a dependency called `stream-shift`. See this link if you are experiencing similar issues https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/2368

New Implementation

```
const transferManager = new TransferManager(bucket);
    // Downloads the files
    await transferManager.downloadFileInChunks(inputPath, {
      destination: downloadFilePath,
    });
```